# Which engine for hosting a perforce server on Google Cloud?

Tags: version-control, google-cloud-platform, perforce

I'm looking for a place to run the perforce service on, since their Helix Cloud has been in beta since early 2015, and doesn't seem like it will leave said beta any time soon.

The problem is that I have little understanding of the whole gimmick. I basically need an engine that can run a service and can store data, so that I and my colleague can connect to it remotely and version our project. I've read their documentation regarding Big Data and Compute Engines, and I still can't figure it out. One seems massive, the other seems more appropriate for a gaming server. I suppose Storage would be the right one but I'm not sure that one can run services.

So do I run it on a VM and turn it off/on when done/using it? Or is there a better way at versioning with perforce in the cloud. Seems kinda pointless running a VM to turn it on and off, since that's what i'm currently doing with my local machine anyway. Unless there is a better solution.

I hope that's the right spot to ask about this, I was referred here by their support page.

PS: We are a small team,50-100 Gigs of versioning storage will last us for ages, please when answering don't assume I need something fancier than it needs to be.

Comment: Why perforce? Could you use another VCS? If so then there are a lot more options than running a VM in the cloud

Comment: As I understand, Perforce is the only version control that can handle large binary files, which is exactly what 3d assets are. I know about SVN, but that isn't integrated into UE4 either.

Out of curiosity, which are said options that do not use a VM on the google cloud platform? Are you referring to the aforementioned SVN or  is it Git that you're pointing to?

Comment: If large binaries are a requirement then Git isn't going to help you, however VSTS might be worth a look. It supports Git but also it's own cenralised VCS which is similar to perforce in many respects. Also [other hosting options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source_code_hosting_facilities) If you really want to manage the infrastructure then obviously there are other IaaS cloud platforms where you can spin up a VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting for a few days and reading the documentation, I have come to the conclusion that the Compute Engine is the only on on GCP that can run a service. Ended up configin a CentOS and keeping it there.